# Initialize ArrayList<Long>

Tags: java, arrays, list, arraylist, long-integer

Why I can initialize ArrayList, like this:

```
ArrayList<Integer> x = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(1,2));
```

But got Error when using:

```
ArrayList<Long> x = new ArrayList<Long>(Arrays.asList(1,2));
```

Comment: numbers by default are int so when java tries to auto-box 1 and 2 it will turn it into wrapper type Integer and Integer isn't the same or any how related to Long

Comment: ``Arrays.asList(1L, 2L)``

Comment: 1,2 are ints and no longs

Answer (score 34, accepted):

### Explanation

Java automatically transforms `int` to `long` if needed.

However, Java **does not do the same** if a transformation from `Integer` to `Long` is needed.

The function `Arrays.asList(...)` returns a `List<E>` with `E` being the type used as parameters. As you use `1, 2, 3` the type is `int`. However the generic usage of **data-types** as `List<int>` is not possible in Java (at least currently). Therefore it automatically transforms `int` to `Integer` and produces a `List<Integer>` object. This process is called **auto-boxing**, Java can do this for all data-types to their corresponding object representation.

If you now use the constructor `new ArrayList<Integer>(List<E> list)` it expects `E` to be something of type `Integer`. So a `List<Integer>` works as input.

But when you use `new ArrayList<Long>(List<E> list)` obviously `E` needs to be of type `Long`. However the object `Integer` is **not of type** `Long` thus it does **not accept** the parameter. The first common type of `Integer` and `Long` is the abstract class `Number` (which also holds `Double`, `Float` and others) ([documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Number.html)).

---

### Solution

So it all revolves around the input `1, 2, 3` being interpreted as `int` instead of `long`. You can fix this by **explicitly** telling Java to **interpret** the numbers as `long`, you do so by appending `l` or `L` after the number:

```
new ArrayList<Long>(Arrays.asList(1L, 2L, 3L));
```

Now you receive a `List<Long>` which then is added to an `ArrayList<Long>`.

---

Note that the same technique can be used to explicitly interpret decimal numbers as `float` instead of `double`: `1.5F` or `1.5f`

Comment: It's important to note that `asList` returns a custom fixed size `ArrayList` and **not** `java.util.ArrayList`.

Comment: @Oleg You are right, did not know that. I'll remove the note from the answer as it's not that useful then.

Answer (score 13):

That's because `1` and `2` are ints and `Arrays.asList(1, 2)` creates a `List<Integer>`.

And the copy constructor of `ArrayList` requires the argument to be of the same generic type.

You have several options but the simplest one is to change the `int`s into `long`s by adding a `L` suffix:

```
List<Long> x = new ArrayList<Long>(Arrays.asList(1L, 2L));
```

Note that with Java 9 you can also write:

```
List<Long> x = List.of(1L, 2L);
```

Comment: It might be woth mentioning that the java 9 version is similar to `Arrays.asList` in that it returns an immutable List - if you want `x` to be mutable, you still need the copy constructor.

Comment: Just to avoid confusion - I'm aware that the list returned by `Arrays.asList` is mutable, but fixed size. The answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46579074/2513200) might also be of interest for future readers.

Answer (score 13):

You have to specify a `Long` number using literal `l` or `L`.

```
List<Long> x = new ArrayList<Long>(Arrays.asList(1L, 2L));
```

Otherwise `1` and `2` are understood as integers resulting in `List<Integer>`.

Answer (score 4):

Because `Arrays.asList(1,2)` will implicitly return a `List<Integer>`.

You can fix this by using the following idiom:

```
ArrayList<Long> x = new ArrayList<Long>(Arrays.asList(1l,2l));
```